# LINQ to SQL, Visual Basic - Listbox Receives the Query NOT the Result

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq

#### Overview

This is a homework assignment using LINQ to SQL in a Visual Basic application. It is correct in most ways except that I have a partially broken result. Rather than adding the result of my second query to my listbox, my code adds a weird representation of the query itself. Below is a description of the DB, followed by my output (intended and actual), and finally my code. Please point me toward the broken concept so I can figure out what I am missing. Thanks much.

#### DB info

I am using two tables, called Members and Payments, from one DB. Members has a primary key called `ID` and also has the fields `first_name` and `last_name`. Payments has a foreign key called `Members_Id`, which is associated to the Member's primary key; Payments also has the payment values under the column `Payments`.

Output should be like this

```
Member name = John Smith
    $48.00,  10/20/2005
    $44.00,  3/11/2006
```

But is this instead

```
Member name = SELECT ([t0].[First_Name] + @p1) + [t0].[Last_Name]
              AS [value]FROM[dbo].[Members] AS [t0].[ID] = @p0

    $48.00,  10/20/2005
    $44.00,  3/11/2006
```

#### My VB Code

```vb
Public Class FormPaymentsGroup
    Private db As New KarateClassesDataContext

Private Sub FormPaymentsGroup_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.PaymentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.KarateDataSet.Payments)

    'Group payments by Member_ID (FKey) in the Payments table. (Working fine)
    Dim IdQuery = From aMember In db.Payments
                Group aMember By aMember.Member_Id
                Into MemberPayments = Group

    For Each memberID In IdQuery
    ' Use the passed member_Id to target the row in the Members table and return the first_name & last_name.
    ' PROBLEM: This only seems to be returning the query itself; not the result.
        Dim currMemberID = memberID.Member_Id
        Dim nameQuery = From aName In db.Members
                        Where aName.ID = currMemberID
                        Select aName.First_Name + " " + aName.Last_Name

        Dim currName = nameQuery.ToString ' Load the query result into a portable variable.

        LbxMemberPayments.Items.Add("Member name = " & currName) ' PROBLEM: This is where the name SHOULD BE posted to the listbox.

        ' This is bound to the Members table but directs it based on the above IdQuery.
        For Each enteredPayment In memberID.MemberPayments
            LbxMemberPayments.Items.Add(vbTab & FormatCurrency(enteredPayment.Amount) & ",  " & enteredPayment.Payment_Date)
        Next
        LbxMemberPayments.Items.Add(vbCr)   ' Carriage return formatting
    Next

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
   Dim currName = nameQuery.ToString
```

to

```
    Dim currName = nameQuery.FirstOrDefault
```

Comment: Thank you!!
This worked. Now I have to go find out why. Have a great day.